# Can't run Cordova / Phonegap app for Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, terminal

I am trying to test a Cordova / Phonegap application using the command:

```
phonegap run android --verbose
```

When I run the command I get the following error:

```
    BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.1.2/tools/ant/build.xml:601: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/alan/Downloads/butterflies-master-1.0.0/cordova/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/build.xml:28: Cannot find /Users/work/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml imported from /Users/alan/Downloads/butterflies-master-1.0.0/cordova/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/build.xml
```

Is it something to do with: `xwalk_core_library`

The app works fine on iOS. The problem just happens when trying to test on Android

Comment: What is your environment? Are you using crosswalk or a custom cordova view? Please add more information.

Comment: @lifeisfoo Yes, using crosswalk. What additional info would you like to see? Thanks